# Run dbus-monitor in system mode as non-root user

Tags: linux, d-bus

Is is possible to monitor the D-Bus calls across the system bus as a non-root user? I want to create a service to capture the raw D-Bus calls in my system, but my preference is to run custom services without root privileges for security reasons. This service will filter out unwanted messages and create a log file for the remainder after sanitizing out any sensitive content values. The goal is to create a log stream that is supplemental to a specific service's log, so that I can verify that every configuration and select read commands being sent are actually being logged correctly by our custom service(s) that provide a D-Bus interface.

I created a system-local.conf to provide users in the "dbusmonitor" group with the ability to "BecomeMonitor", which results in a slightly different error message than users that are not in that group, but does not result in the desired behavior.

Contents of */etc/dbus-1/system-local.conf*:

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <policy group="dbusmonitor">
    <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.DBus"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring"
           send_member="BecomeMonitor"
           send_type="method_call"/>
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Normal user output of dbus-monitor for the NetworkManager destination. When a dbus call is made, nothing appears in the output.

```
[test@localhost ~]$ groups
test

[test@localhost ~]$ dbus-monitor --system "destination='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'"

dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: "Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.461" (uid=1002 pid=6471 comm="dbus-monitor --system destination='org.freedesktop" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring" member="BecomeMonitor" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)". Falling back to eavesdropping.

signal time=1661974390.087332 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.461 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.461"
```

Here is the output of the same dbus-monitor command for a user that is a member of the privileged group; note that the error message is slightly different. Again, the dbus calls are not captured.

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ groups
admin wheel dbusmonitor

[admin@localhost ~]$ dbus-monitor --system "destination='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'"

dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: "rejected attempt to call BecomeMonitor by connection :1.528 (uid=1000 pid=9157 comm="dbus-monitor --system destination='org.freedesktop" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023") with uid 1000". Falling back to eavesdropping.

signal time=1661978040.536692 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.528 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.528"
```

Here is the output of the same dbus-monitor command for the root user. The dbus call to "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.state" is successfully captured, which is the desired behavior.

```
[root@localhost ~]#  dbus-monitor --system "destination='org.freedesktop.NetworkManager'"

signal time=1661979771.623836 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.546 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.546"
signal time=1661979771.623861 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.546 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.546"

method call time=1661979774.507096 sender=:1.547 -> destination=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable; member=Introspect
method call time=1661979774.508390 sender=:1.547 -> destination=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager serial=3 path=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager; interface=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager; member=state
```

If it makes a difference, I am testing on RHEL8. Note that switching SELinux to Permissive mode had no effect on the issue.

Is there another privilege I need to assign to the "dbusmonitor" group in the system-local.conf file? Or is this ability secondarily restricted somewhere else?

Comment: After taking a look at the source code, I think the answer is that it is not possible by design. See the if statements at lines 180 and 184 of the source (https://fossies.org/linux/dbus/bus/driver.c). The only loophole appears to be if the monitor service is run by the same user account that owns the process that published the D-Bus interface I want to monitor, but I need to test that to be certain. Being part of the same user group will not be sufficient.

Comment: I did a quick test where I registered a service on the system message bus using the "admin" user, and was able to call the method I exposed from all three users (root, admin, and test). Unfortunately, the "admin" user was still unable to monitor the messages. :(

Comment: Same issue here. Have burnt hours into it. I guess it is restricted by design, didn't look into the code though. Gave up and using root for monitoring atm.

Comment: You can use gdbus from glib2. It seems to be able to monitor the system bus without root. YMMV